# Non blocking io in ruby MRI and eventmachine

Tags: multithreading, nonblocking, eventmachine

As far as I understand, non blocking io in mri makes GIL to release lock. In em, according to this article: http://www.paperplanes.de/2011/4/25/eventmachine-how-does-it-work.html, non blocking is achieved according to system calls like `select`, `epoll`, `kqueue`. Is there a way to do non blocking in pure ruby (that means, other thread is starting, when I am waiting for something)?

Answer (score 1):

GIL doesn't come into play with EM since everything happens inside the same thread (except EM.defer blocks ofc)

You can use non-blocking code from pure ruby, best way to see how is to take a look at the pure ruby implementation of the EM reactor: https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine/blob/master/lib/em/pure_ruby.rb